# Mergefield from Segment/List into Mergefield from DE

Tags: dataextensions, merge-field

Mergefield into a Mergefield essentially

I have a segment/list as a DE - Columns (email | brand | lang )

I have a 2nd DE - Columns - ( lang | image )

my image uses mergefields from the 1st DE/Segment/List to form a URL

example image - `http:/www.test.com/%%brand%%%%lang%%.jpg`

I have a lookup that brings the image column in. This works but it does not merge in brand and language to form the url. Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Please post the code for your lookup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "mergefields" or personalization strings can only be referenced with the double-percent notation if they are columns in your sending Data Extension or are Profile Attributes.  Any value retrieved outside of those two things needs to be referenced using the [**v() AMPScript function**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/v/#v).  For example:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

I'd also recommend using the [**concat()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/concat/) function to build your URLs:

```
%%[
var @URL, @brand, @lang
set @lang = AttributeValue("Language")
set @brand = AttributeValue("brandcode")
set @URL= concat("http://",@brand,"xxxxx.com/?ul=", @lang)

]%%

<a href="%%=redirectto(@URL)=%%" alias="test URL"/>link text</a>
```

Reference:

[**AMPScript Lookup Examples**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)

Comment: so i'm working on this again and have hit a dead end.

Comment: so i'm working on this again and have hit a dead end.  I have this %%[ Set [AT]SubLang = Language
Set[AT]SubBC = BRANDCODE and in my DE row I have this http://%%=v([AT]SubBC)=%%xxxxx.com/?ul=%%=v([AT]SubLang)=%%".                         The problem is that it seems to replace my personalization fields and then bring in the value from the DE

Comment: I've updated the second example in my answer.  Give something like that a try.

Comment: it works but when i put this in my DE and use a lookup to pull it, i get nothing.

Comment: DE Column = html (<a href="%%=redirectto(@URL)=%%" alias="test URL"/>link text</a>)

Comment: once i send it as a test, all i get is %%=redirectto(@URL)=%%

Comment: If you're pulling the AMPScript from a DE, then you need to wrap it with a `treatascontent()` function after you retrieve it -- to force the AMPScript to get evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Works perfectly and exactly what i was looking for